# Orientation of $\Delta$-complex structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I think it's better to explain my question by example.

When we compute the (simplicial) homology of, for example a Klein bottle, we first give $\Delta$-complex structure on CW-complex structure of Klein bottle. For example
[image: .]

We label the vertices to give an orientation. In this case, if we let $U$ be the upper triangle and $L$ be the lower triangle then $\partial U = b+a-c$ and $\partial L =a-b-c$.

But we can give different orientation like this:
[image: ..]

In this case, $\partial U = b+a-c$ and $\partial L = c+b-a$.

1. If we give different orientation, then $\partial L$ in our case has different value. Does it matter?
2. In the second image, the label of the vertex doesn't match (upper right vertex). Does it matter?

I think I'm basically confusing the concept of orientation. Could you explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the orientation with $\partial L = a-b-c$ and $L'$ be the orientation with $\partial L' = c+b-a$. Then $\partial L' = -\partial L$, so one might as well regard $L'$ as being equal to $-L$, in the free abelian group generated by $U$ and $L$.

In general, you want to treat $X$ with vertices relabelled $[v_{\sigma0}, v_{\sigma1}, \cdots, v_{\sigma n}]$ as being equal to $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) X$, where $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$ is the [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of the permutation $\sigma$.

And then considering $L'$ instead of $L$ would be tantamount to choosing the basis $\{U, -L\}$ instead of $\{U, L\}$ of $C_2 = \Bbb Z U \oplus \Bbb Z L$.

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph. Could you explain that with example?

Comment: you switched the vertices from [0,1,2] to [0,2,1], which is an odd permutation, so $L' = -L$.

Comment: Ok, so the orientation doesn't matter for computation of homology. What about the second question?

Comment: One vertex can only have one name, because otherwise things like $\partial a$ wouldn't be well-defined. In fact I think all 4 of your vertices should be named 0.

Comment: I mean those labels are understood as label of 0-cell in $\Delta_2$ so the label I gave is for $U,L$ not for single vertex in $\Delta$-complex structure.